# Why jQuery height() and width() methods sometimes take too long to calculate element height and width

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have noticed jQuery `height()` and `width()` methods sometimes take too long to calculate an element height and width. How can i optimize it for IE8+ and latest version of Chrome and Firefox?

Edit - 
Found that jQuery is using offsetHeight/offsetWidth that can return 0 if you've done certain DOM modifications to the element recently. So it calls it in a setTimeout call after you've modified the element. It could be the one of the reason of these methods sometimes takes more time.

Is there any way to overcome this issue?

Comment: What exactly is "too long" for you ?

Comment: longer than accessing a property of an object.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the values in variables, instead call methods all the time.

Comment: these values keep changing,  i need the latest values.